# How to change Column Name change based on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are two tables Table_1 and Table_2

Table_1

```
  Col 0   Col 1   Col2

   1       2       3

   4       1      2
```

Table_2

```
   ColNo    ColName

    0         A

    1         D

    2         E
```

now i have to change only the Table_1 column's name based on Table_2 ColNo value.

so the ultimate Table_1 will be

```
  A       D      E

  1       2      3

  4       1      2
```

How can i do this in sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @Command = @Command + 'Exec sys.sp_rename @objname = N''Table_1.Col'+CAST(ColNo AS VARCHAR(10))+''', @newname = '''+ColName+''', @objtype = ''COLUMN'';'
FROM Table_2

--Select @Command

Exec (@Command)
```

Comment: `@Command` variable contain execution command to change your column name. You can execute `@Command` variable.

Comment: I have similar query in oracle. Can you suggest how this can be written in oracle?